# What is the similar things like the Java's Robot class in Cocoas?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to use Cocoas to control the user input and mouse movement. In Java, In Java, I can go these things using the Robot class. Which library/class I should check in the Cocoas framework? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to move the mouse programmatically you can use [Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and

[`CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition)

in particular. For more information check out this chapter: [Controlling the Mouse Cursor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/MouseCursor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004269-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa, mouse movements can be tracked by a combination of NSWindow, NSView and NSResponder.

You must be knowing there is something called Responder Chain, where each of the object in the chain gets the chance to response based on if they are first responder.

And there are few methods you would like to check:

1. mouseDown:
2. mouseDragged:
3. mouseUp:
4. mouseMoved:  etc.

For more you may read this [Handling Mouse Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html).

Comment: I want to control the mouse and keyboard instead of Listening the event. I think the case here is very different.

Comment: Oh, failed to understood the requirement.